# How to use JSLint to scan only for eval errors?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I want to scan my Javascript code only for eval errors using JSLint. I want to tolerate all the other errors. I know I need to set all other error types as "true" individually, but there are a lot of options. Is there any shorter method for doing this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use your text editor or IDE and use *Find* command and search for *"eval"* ?

Comment: I could. But I would have to open each file and check it. Currently, I am using command line to scan through a list of javascript files. Plus, I am using JSLint because I want to check if the Javascript code is vulnerable. Not all the uses of eval could cause it the code to be vulnerable (and so I am using JSLint to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ (probably amongst plenty other text editors) will let you open lots of files quickly, and has a `search in all open files` feature. That will probably serve your need.

As for JSLint, last time I checked it was a religious tool that put enforcing a style before being helpful, it has some configuration options, but if you want to cherry-pick features it doesn't work. If you want that consider trying [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: Ouch.  Say what you will about JSLint, dude; at least it's an ethos. And the code's pretty clean.  You could hack to just show `eval` pretty easily if you want and have enough reason to do so. And **note there are a few things you'd have to search for in your solution** - [`document.write` is a form of eval](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/03/31/jslint-messages-document-write-can-be-a-form-of-eval/), for instance.

Comment: @ruffin When you need a tool an ethos just isn't very useful. And yes, you could hack JSLint to be more tooly and less ethosy. In fact someone has already done that, the result is JSHint.

Comment: What I mean by that quote is that it's much easier (and more productive) to standardize on JSLint than to have no "religion" at all.  ;)  I wouldn't let claims of religiosity be arguments against its implementation in general.  It's a very useful tool, whether you agree with Crockford about all of his subjective decisions or not.  I'm glad JSHint works well for you; my main point is that that's or a modified JSLint is probably going to be a better solution than searching for every eval equivalent in files.

Comment: @ruffin OP has a problem, JSLint won't solve it, I explain why and suggest two alternative solutions. Whether submitting to the JSLint religion in general is a good a idea is a completely different question that I did not try to answer. You seem to feel a need to answer it despite it being off topic.

Comment: I'll drop after this: To say, "As for JSLint, _last time I checked it was a religious tool that put enforcing a style before being helpful_" does nothing to answer the OP's question. That's unearned bad press, which I qualified. And **JSLint can solve this problem** if you modify its very clean code. I suggested doing that -- or, as you've said, using JSHint -- would be a better solution than searching files for each possible eval() equivalent, and showed why. That's a potentially useful comment to add to the answer. You gave two answers; the JSHint half is potentially better. Fair enough?